# How do I link to libcinder.a for iOS in version 0.9.1+?

Tags: ios, linker-errors, cinder

*Cross-posted from [here](https://discourse.libcinder.org/t/ios-static-libraries-gone-from-0-9-1-2/1700) in case I can get more eyeballs.*

I’m getting back onto an old iOS app of mine developed in the pre-0.9 era, and I made some progress updating everything to use Cinder 0.9.2 and C++14 (baby steps…). Now, I hit a pretty massive roadblock with linking – in fact, not just with my app but with pretty much anything for iOS under samples.

I used to link to those static libraries (`libcinder.a`) who lived in `lib/ios/`, which I understand are now supposed to have their own `Release` and `Debug` directories in there. However, I can’t seem to find any of that, and I can’t figure out how to retrieve them. Am I supposed to compile the library from the sources even if I downloaded the zip from the website?

Sorry, this must be obvious, but unfortunately I haven’t touched Cinder very much after the 0.9.0 release :(

**EDIT** I tried a `fullbuild.sh` just in case and I ended up with what follows below. So it seems the macOS build went fine, but the iOS one did not. I should say, this is using Xcode 11.7 on Catalina.

```
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/morpheu5/src/cinder_0.9.2_mac/proj/xcode/cinder.xcodeproj -target cinder_iphone -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos13.7

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: AppKit is not available when building for iOS. (in target 'cinder_iphone' from project 'cinder')
error: Cocoa is not available when building for iOS. (in target 'cinder_iphone' from project 'cinder')

** BUILD FAILED **

Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/morpheu5/src/cinder_0.9.2_mac/proj/xcode/cinder.xcodeproj -target cinder_iphone -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos13.7

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: AppKit is not available when building for iOS. (in target 'cinder_iphone' from project 'cinder')
error: Cocoa is not available when building for iOS. (in target 'cinder_iphone' from project 'cinder')

** BUILD FAILED **

Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/morpheu5/src/cinder_0.9.2_mac/proj/xcode/cinder.xcodeproj -target cinder_iphone_sim -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator13.7

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework CoreVideo.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework AVFoundation.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework CoreMedia.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework CoreVideo.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework AVFoundation.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework CoreMedia.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
error: AppKit is not available when building for iOS Simulator. (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
error: Cocoa is not available when building for iOS Simulator. (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
error: QTKit is not available when building for iOS Simulator. (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')

** BUILD FAILED **

Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/morpheu5/src/cinder_0.9.2_mac/proj/xcode/cinder.xcodeproj -target cinder_iphone_sim -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator13.7

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework CoreVideo.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework AVFoundation.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework CoreMedia.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework CoreVideo.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework AVFoundation.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
warning: Product libcinder.a cannot weak-link framework CoreMedia.framework (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
error: AppKit is not available when building for iOS Simulator. (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
error: Cocoa is not available when building for iOS Simulator. (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')
error: QTKit is not available when building for iOS Simulator. (in target 'cinder_iphone_sim' from project 'cinder')

** BUILD FAILED **
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is somewhere with how the project is configured. [This PR](https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/pull/2180) solves the issue for me, I was able to rebuild Cinder and everything was in the right place again.